# How to run custom checkstyle rules?

Tags: checkstyle

I want to create my rules. I saw this link: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html
And I create a simple maven project, it contains only one class :

```
package com.posco.myapp;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.*;
public class MethodLimitCheck extends Check{

 private static final int DEFAULT_MAX = 30;
    private int max = DEFAULT_MAX;

    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens()
    {
        return new int[]{TokenTypes.CLASS_DEF, TokenTypes.INTERFACE_DEF};
    }

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast)
    {
        // find the OBJBLOCK node below the CLASS_DEF/INTERFACE_DEF
        DetailAST objBlock = ast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.OBJBLOCK);
        // count the number of direct children of the OBJBLOCK
        // that are METHOD_DEFS
        int methodDefs = objBlock.getChildCount(TokenTypes.METHOD_DEF);
        // report error if limit is reached
        if (methodDefs > this.max) {
            log(ast.getLineNo(),
                "too many methods, only " + this.max + " are allowed");
        }
        if (methodDefs < this.max) {
            log(ast.getLineNo(),
                "too many methods, only " + this.max + " are allowed");
        }
   }
```

And I put this code in my config.xml file

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <!-- myCheck.                     -->
    <module name="com.posco.myapp.MethodLimitCheck">
    </module>
```

and then, I run with command line (after using maven to create myjar):

```
java -classpath my-core-1.0.jar:checkstyle-5.5-all.jar com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c config.xml
```

The error is: classNotFoundException: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.gui.Main

you would like to hep me !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, you can add checkstyle plugin to maven pom.xml. So whenever you are bulding project or running maven install it will check for checkstyle errors. Checkstyle setup is very simple like to add some lines in pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks Rani, may be you are misunderstand. I want to export MyRuleProject to a jar file. And then, I will check another project(or .java file) which not use maven by using this command:

java -classpath my-core-1.0.jar:checkstyle-5.5-all.jar com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c sun_checks.xml -r (myfile)